# Как сделать чтобы ссылка в навбаре не уезжала?

Tags: html, css

Вот вся проблема. Как я понял она появилась из-за того что картинка в диве больше размера навбара, но что делать я не знаю( я просто полный ноль в css, помогите пожалуйста:

```css
.navbar {
  background: white;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 4px;
}

.navbar a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.navbar a.active, .navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.navbar .auth {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
        <a href="/">test</a>
        <a href="/test" class="active">test</a>
    <div class="auth">
      <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2CCIYPXEAsw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAB8/PJzx2th4x4I/photo.jpg?sz=64" width="25">
      <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a>
    </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.navbar {
  background: white;
  height: 20%;
  padding: 4px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar a {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 6px;
  padding: 7px;
}

.navbar a.active,
.navbar a:hover {
  color: black;
}

.navbar .auth {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.navbar .auth img {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="nav-links">
    <a href="/">test</a>
    <a href="/test" class="active">test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="auth">
    <img style="border-radius: 50%" src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2CCIYPXEAsw/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAB8/PJzx2th4x4I/photo.jpg?sz=64" width="25">
    <a rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out">Logout</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Как вариант на флексе

Comment: большое спасибо!